# C Beginners' Query: char array program - not getting desired output

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Newbie Question:
Hi! Intended to study how one array populates another (initialised) array during copying. So I ran the following bit of code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char strA[]= "\nThis is array 'a'.\n";
char strB[] = "ABCDEFGABCDEFGABCDEFG";

int main()
{
  /* Copy one string to another using pointers */

  char *pA, *pB;
  puts(strA);
  puts(strB);
  pA=strA;
  pB=strB;
  puts(pA);
  puts(pB);
  while(*pA!='\0') {
    *pB++ = *pA++;
    puts(pB);
  }
  *pB='\0';
  puts(strB);

  return 0;
}
```

What I expected was to see how `strA[]` copied itself into `strB[]` at each step i.e. somewhere in the middle `strB[]` would have `strA[]` elements copied and remaining `strB[]` elements. But I could not find `strA[]` elements copied into `strB[]`, though `strB[]` elements kept decreasing. The following is the output:

```
This is array 'a'.

ABCDEFGABCDEFGABCDEFG

This is array 'a'.

ABCDEFGABCDEFGABCDEFG
BCDEFGABCDEFGABCDEFG
CDEFGABCDEFGABCDEFG
DEFGABCDEFGABCDEFG
EFGABCDEFGABCDEFG
FGABCDEFGABCDEFG
GABCDEFGABCDEFG
ABCDEFGABCDEFG
BCDEFGABCDEFG
CDEFGABCDEFG
DEFGABCDEFG
EFGABCDEFG
FGABCDEFG
GABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
BCDEFG
CDEFG
DEFG
EFG
FG
G

This is array 'a'.

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.025 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Am I missing something basic here? Any explanations would be of great help.

Comment: `pB` advances through `strB`, thus `puts(pB)` will print the string from the current position. If you want to print the whole, partially overwritten string, call `puts(strB)` inside the loop.

Comment: You're advancing the pointer in your loop, towards the end of the string. As you're treating said pointer as the beginning of your string, you're effectively moving the beginning of your string backwards. Try using two separate pointers, one for printing, and one for looping.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're incrementing `pB` before you call `puts(pB)` in the loop, you're only seeing the part of `strB` starting from the current value of `pB`.

Change your loop to:

```
while(*pA!='\0') {
    *pB++ = *pA++;
    puts(strB);
}
```

and you'll see the entire string with the intermediate changes after each step.

Answer (score 0):

You are increment pB pointer before printing pB. Could you modify your while like below?

```
while(*pA!='\0') {

    *pB = *pA++;

    puts(pB);

    pB++;

}
```